# Why Does Image Read Null When I Try To Delete My Category?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to find a way to delete my category that I have created. I have the image stored in my public folder and I get the error attempt to read image is null, I think the error has to do with category_id being null. How can I retrieve it for my category object?

```
//Controller class
class Index extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public $category_id;

    //setting category_id
    public function deleteCategory($category_id)
    {
        $this->category_id = $category_id;
    }

    
    public function destroyCategory() {
        $category = Category::find($this->category_id);
        // dd($this);
        $path = 'uploads/category/'.$category->image;
        if (File::exists($path)) {
            File::delete($path);
        }
        $category->delete();
        session()->flash('message', 'Category Deleted');
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $categories = Category::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);

        return view('livewire.admin.category.index', ['categories' => $categories]);
    }
}
```

this is my component blades file that accompanies it.

```
//my blade file
 <div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Category Delete</h1>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <form wire:submit.prevent="destroyCategory">

         
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <h6>Are you sure you want to delete this data?</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes. Delete</button>
                </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @if(session('message'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">{{session('message')}}</div>
            @endif
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>
                    Category
                    <a href="{{url('admin/category/create')}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float end">Add Category</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                {{-- display all categories using livewire --}}
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$category->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$category->name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$category->status == '1' ? "Hidden" : "Visible"}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{url('admin/category/'.$category->id.'/edit')}}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                                <a href="#" wire:click="deleteCategory({{$category->id}})" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteModal">
                                    Delete
                                </a>
                        </tr> 
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>

                </table>
                <div>
                {{$categories->links()}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
@push('script')
<script>
    window.addEventListener('close-modal', event => {
        $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
    })
</script>
@endpush
```

Comment: Did you check if the `$category_id` is really set if you  click the delete button on the table ?

Comment: It is not set it seems.

Comment: Instead of calling the `deleteCategory` method you should use the `$set('category_id', {{ $category->id }})`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add my sugestion as a comment, however is to long and it doesn't look good when i add the code, so i need to add a post.

I see that you are using `deleteCategory()` to get `category_id` and set it  on a public varaible `public $category_id;`, when you get the variable then you try to delete the category with `destroyCategory()`.

If that is true you don't need to create 2 functions for that,
so instead try and use this:

```
public function deleteCategory($category_id) {
    $category = Category::find($category_id);
    $path = 'uploads/category/'.$category->image;
    // dd($path); <- try this on the debbuger, to see the path
    if (File::exists($path)) {
        File::delete($path);
    }
    $category->delete();
    session()->flash('message', 'Category Deleted');
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal');
}
```

Just use the function deleteCategory with the code of destroyCategory, and let the paramenter $category_id, because deleteCategory gets the id from the view

```
wire:click="deleteCategory({{$category->id}})"
```